# SET game: how to generate decks of 12 cards with 6 hidden sets?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling

This question was initially the second part of [another question](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/10820/how-to-generate-feasible-sets-with-a-mip) and justifies a new post.

The context is a game called [Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28card_game%29#:%7E:text=Basic%20combinatorics%20of%20Set):

> In the game, certain combinations of three cards are said to make up a
> "set". For each one of the four categories of features — color,
> number, shape, and shading — the three cards must display that feature
> as either a) all the same, or b) all different. Put another way: For
> each feature the three cards must avoid having two cards showing one
> version of the feature and the remaining card showing a different
> version.

Apps online generate decks of $12$ cards with exactly $6$ hidden sets. The goal is to find the $6$ hidden sets, and once all $6$ are found, a new deck of 12 cards is generated, with $6$ hidden sets. And so forth.

Is it possible to generate such decks with a MIP?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Omega$ be the set of all the *sets*, and let $C$ the complete deck of cards. Let $y_s$ be a binary variable that takes value $1$ if and only if set $s \in \Omega$ is used. And let $x_c$ be a binary variable that takes value $1$ if and only if card $c\in C$ is used.

To generate a deck of $12$ cards with $6$ sets, minimize a dummy objective function subject to:

- The deck must have $12$ cards:
  $$
  \sum_{c\in C} x_c = 12 
  $$
- The deck must have $6$ sets:
  $$
  \sum_{s\in \Omega} y_s= 6 
  $$
- If set $s$ is selected, then cards from this set are selected:
  $$
  y_s\le x_c \quad \forall s\in \Omega, \quad\forall c \in s 
  $$
- If a set $s$ is not selected, then its $3$ cards can not be selected (courtesy of @prubin):
  $$
  \sum_{c\in s}x_c \le 2+y_s \quad \forall s \in \Omega
  $$

To generate a new deck given a solution $\hat{y}$, you can add a no good cut:
$$
\sum_{s\in \Omega|\hat{y_s}=1}y_s \le 5
$$

Note that brute force would require generating decks from the $\binom{81}{12}=7.07243201847 × 10^{13}$ possible decks of $12$ cards, and checking if they contain $6$ of the $1 080$ sets.

Comment: I think you also need a constraint saying that if set $s$ is *not* selected, then the three cards in $s$ cannot all be present. Otherwise, your deck might contain more than 6 sets. $\sum_{c\in s} x_c \le 2 + y_s\, \forall s\in \Omega$ should do it, I think.

Comment: @prubin I think you are right, thanks!